# React / Is it possible to return an html tag with an event function?

Tags: reactjs

Hello

I would like to display information during a MouseOver. But it seems it is not the right method to use :

```js
 return (
        <div className="item" key={i}
          onMouseOver = {(e) => {
            return (<div className="prompt">{variable}</div>)
          }}
```

What would be the correct way ?

Comment: Use the event to trigger a function that creates and renders an element with that information

Comment: Is it not what I am doing ?

Comment: @fransua where do you think this element would be injected in the DOM when you didn't specify any place?

Comment: it was an extract of my code

Comment: So you expect output like this yes? `<div className="item" key="0"
          onMouseOver="<div className="prompt">{variable}</div>">` ?

Comment: I guess I am wrong. Please don't shoot the beginner.

Comment: I just wanted to show you that it's more logical than it appears at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [showElement, setShowElement] = useState(false);

return (
  <div className="item" key={i}
    onMouseOver = {(e) => {
      setShowElement(true)
    }}
  >
   {showElement && <div className="prompt">{variable}</div>
  </div>
)
```